# Burninate "managment" tag in careers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, stack-overflow-jobs

There is a tag [managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managment) in the [careers site](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?tags=managment). There is also a tag [management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/management). [managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managment) is a typo. Please BURNINATE!

Comment: So… many… puns.

Comment: Burn them all and let God sort them out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaaannnnnddddd ..... It's gone! (I fixed the spelling)

Comment: Successful burnination… so satisfying.